# Stop showing default progress bar in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

While uploading a large file via XMLHTTPRequest with multipart/form-data enctype in chrome.By default a small uploading progress bar with a percentage is showing on bottom-left corner of the chrome browser. sample image has shown below.

[image]

How can we stop this default progress bar showing on chrome by java script

Comment: I doubt this is possible. But even if you could, I'd strongly oppose to hiding the progress bar. Not unless you provide for an alternative progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

### it's seen as a security feature, and there isn't a way to turn it off.